# http_code 0 with Redhat php curl request

Tags: php, redhat

I can use lynx to access a website from the server fine. When I try to access the same website with a php curl instruction I get `http_code=>0` from `curl_getinfo($ch);` The same php code on another redhat server in the same data centre works fine, I have admin access to the server.

I have tried php 7.4 and php 8.0. Curl is enabled when I call `phpinfo();` I am unsure how to debug this error!

Are there steps I should try to rectify this? Could I have conflicting CURL applications or should I completely remove and reinstall php, php-curl, or apache or do something else? If I should do those things please provide some commands to do that.
It is RHEL 8.8

This is the output from curl_getinfo($ch);

```
Array ( [url] =>
https://..... [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.055895 [namelookup_time] => 0.105978 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0
[ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => [appconnect_time_us] => 0
[connect_time_us] => 0 [namelookup_time_us] => 105978
[pretransfer_time_us] => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 [total_time_us] => 55895 )
```

I have also asked this question on stack overflow but I feel it may be a server setup question rather than something for SO. Here is the SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77479471/http-code-0-with-redhat-php-curl

Comment: Usually 0 means the connection was closed, are you sure you can open a port and actually send HTTP  GET and get anything back at all?

Comment: Yes. From the same server I use lynx to the same web address and it works fine. I run the same php file on a different server and it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

This worked. It opened up permissions for PHP. The full answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201308/curl-not-working-from-web-browser-on-red-hat-apache-php-aws